# Laravel 4 TokenMissMatchException with Plupload

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, csrf, plupload

I'm trying to upload files with Plupload but I always get TokenMissMatchException.

```
// Route
Route::post("/posts/gallery", "PostsController@uploadGallery");
// Controller action
    public function uploadGallery(){
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $destinationPath = public_path() . '/imgs';
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = "post-" . str_random(12) . "." . $extension;

        $inFile = $file->getRealPath();
        $outFile = public_path() . "/imgs/" . $filename;

        $image = new Imagick($inFile);
        $image->thumbnailImage(550, 0);
        if($image->writeImage($outFile)){
            return Response::json(["response" => "ok", "img" => $filename]);
        }else{
            return Response::json(["response" => "error"]);
        }
    }
```

This is my attempt to fix this. I tried to add `_token` to request but it's not picking it up:

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
            runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
            url : "{{ URL::action('PostsController@uploadGallery') }}",
            chunk_size: '1mb',
            rename : true,
            dragdrop: true,

            filters : {
                max_file_size : '3mb',
                mime_types: [
                    {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
                ]
            },
            resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
            flash_swf_url : "<?php echo public_path() . '/js/Moxie.swf'; ?>",
            silverlight_xap_url : "<?php echo public_path() . '/js/Moxie.xap'; ?>",
            prevent_duplicates: true,
            multipart_params : {
                "_token" : $("[name=_token]").val()
            }
        });
```

In filters.php I have this:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
    $token = Request::ajax() ? Request::header('x-csrf-token') : Input::get('_token');
    if (Session::token() != $token){
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

Can someone help me with this?

UPDATE:

Html form for uploading files:

```
<div class="imageGallery">
    {{ Form::open() }}
        <div id="uploader">
            <p>Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</p>
        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
```

// hidden input field

```
<input type="hidden" value="VJRUpvq92oYxCsNHVBi5TqqkU6I6CQayay6x7L0m" name="_token">
```

Comment: Does `console.log($("input[name=_token]").val())` return anything? I only ask cause the selector looks wonky to me (but I could be imagining things).

Comment: No it doesn't return anything. I also tried to execute $("input[name=_token]").val() in Firebug console but still nothing

Comment: Huh. Now that is really odd... Only thing I can think of is you're getting some other error that's preventing any other JS from running. Anything in your console when you load the page/make the request?

Comment: How about `$("[name='_token']")`, or `$("input[name='_token']")`. Have you looked at the source of the page to make sure the input is actually there? Make sure it isn't in a partial you forgot to include, or there isn't some javascript somewhere that is deleting the element for some reason.

Comment: $("input[name='_token']") is working. Thank you @patricus

Comment: @Alen Glad that it is working. I have updated my answer to include the solution to this secondary issue and a little explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the upload is being done via ajax, your `csrf` filter is expecting the token to be in the 'x-csrf-token' header, not the input.

Instead of adding the token to the `multipart_params`, try adding it to the `headers`:

```
$("#uploader").pluploadQueue({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
    url : "{{ URL::action('PostsController@uploadGallery') }}",
    chunk_size: '1mb',
    rename : true,
    dragdrop: true,
    filters : {
        max_file_size : '3mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
        ]
    },
    resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
    flash_swf_url : "<?php echo public_path() . '/js/Moxie.swf'; ?>",
    silverlight_xap_url : "<?php echo public_path() . '/js/Moxie.xap'; ?>",
    prevent_duplicates: true,
    headers: {
        "x-csrf-token" : $("[name=_token]").val()
    }
});
```

### Edit

In addition to the above change, it was determined that the javascript was not finding the _token input element to get the value. The solution to that issue was to add quotes around the value in the CSS attribute selector.

The javascript that ended up working:

```
$("input[name='_token']").val()
```

The CSS3 docs regarding attribute selectors can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors). Although some browsers work without the quotes, the examples they provide show the selector values being quoted.

Comment: I have the same error as before even with your new code

Comment: Can you update your question with debugging information from the csrf filter?  What are the values of `Request::ajax()`, `Request::header('x-csrf-token')`, `Input::get('_token')`, `$token`, and `Session::token()` when an upload is done?

Comment: I get TokenMismatchException. $token is empty while Session::token() contains token

Comment: @Alen `$token` is empty, but why? Is it an ajax call or not? Does the request contain the header or not? In your javascript, does `$("[name=_token]").val()` actually return a value?

Comment: $("[name=_token]").val() returns empty string. And yes, it is ajax call

Comment: @Alen Well, if `$("[name=_token]").val()` is returning an empty string, that is the issue. You need to update your javascript to actually get the csrf token from wherever it is stored in the page.

Comment: Yes, but how to update. I have hidden input field with name=_token which is not empty, but jQuery is not picking up its value

Comment: @Alen Please update your question with the html containing your _token input field, and the code used to generate the html.